# how to erase several characters in a cell?

Tags: r, erase

I would like to erase characters "(B)" in the code column, so then I could do "summarise" the 'stock_needed'. My data looks like this.

```
  code   stock_need 
(B)1234    200          
(B)5678    240      
1234       700          
5678       200          
0123       200
```

to be like this.

```
code   stock_need 
1234       200          
5678       240      
1234       700          
5678       200          
0123       200
```

How could these "(B)" erased? Thanx in advance

Comment: No attempt is made at solving the problem.

Comment: @RonakShah sorry I forgot to do it. Thanx so much before, mate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What are other patterns your data has? If it's always `"(B)"` you can do

```
sub("\\(B\\)", "", df$code)
#[1] "1234" "5678" "1234" "5678" "0123"
```

Or if it could be any character do

```
sub("\\([A-Z]\\)", "", df$code)
```

You could also extract only the numbers from `Code`

```
sub(".*?(\\d+).*", "\\1", df$code)
```

You might want to wrap output of `sub` in `as.numeric` or `as.integer` to get numeric/integer output.

---

We can also use `readr`

```
readr::parse_number(df$code)
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need to do two things:

- remove the unnecessary part of the string
- convert the string to numeric.

Say, we load your data frame:

```
df <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="code   stock_need 
(B)1234    200          
(B)5678    240      
1234       700          
5678       200          
0123       200 ")
```

First, we replace the column "code" with something without the parentheses:

```
df$code <- gsub("\\(B\\)", "", df$code)
```

Explanation: why the weird `\\`? Because if we wrote `(B)`, `gsub` would treat the parentheses in a special way. Parentheses have a special meaning in regular expressions, and the first argument to `gsub` is a [regular expression](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/machine-learning/advanced-techniques/regular-expressions-string-manipulation-r/tutorial/).

Next, we make a number vector out of it:

```
df$code <- as.numeric(df$code)
```